# Strong convergence of line integral over $C_0(\mathbb R^2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

I am preparing for a functional analysis exam, but I am a little stuck with this problem left in class:

> Let $X=C_0(\mathbb R^2)$ the closure compactly supported continuous functions in $C_b(\mathbb R^2)$ under the uniform norm. Consider the sequence
> $$\langle f_n,u\rangle \doteq\int_0^{2\pi} u(a_n \cos \theta,b_n \sin \theta)\;\mathrm d\theta.$$
> Where $(a_n),(b_n)$ are real sequences converging to $1$ and $0$ respectively. We are asked to study the strong and weak$^*$ convergence of the sequence.

It is easy to see, using bump functions, that $\Vert f_n \Vert_{X^*}=2\pi$ for all $n$. Thus we must have strong convergence, from the fact that it also weakly converges in the $\sigma(X^*,X)$ topology. I don’t know if I am missing something important, but I didn’t even use the definition of $C_0(\mathbb R^2)$.